# Нужна ли запятая перед "Когда тебе удобно"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Предложение "Создавай рекламный контент, когда тебе удобно"

Вопрос: нужна ли запятая перед "когда"?

Answer (score 1):

Нужна. На цельное выражение не тянет.
*Создавай рекламный контЕнт, когда тебе удОбно.*

Сравнить:
*Создавай рекламный контент когда угОдно.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146